# Ads in my Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, ads

In my wordpress Site I am viewing these links when checking the page speed from `http://gtmetrix.com/`
Anyone please tell me how I can remove these links or which plugin has implemented them?

```
Add Logo to Admin
All In One SEO Pack
Allow PHP in Posts and Pages
Bootstrap Buttons
Breadcrumb NavXT
Custom Permalinks
Disable Comments
Download Manager
Easy Add Thumbnail
Events Manager
Gallery Carousel Without JetPack
Google XML Sitemaps
Gravity Forms
Hide Admin Bar
Insert PHP
Limit Login Attempts
Meta Slider
Ninja Forms
Online Backup for WordPress
Page Builder by SiteOrigin
PHP Code Widget
Regenerate Thumbnails
Role Scoper
Use Google Libraries
Vimeography
W3 Total Cache
WP Job Manager
WP Project Manager
```

These are the links I wish to find or remove the plugin that has them

```
   http://frontlinehq.com/tools.php
    http://frontlinehq.com/index.php
    http://frontlinehq.com/css/skins/2.css
    http://frontlinehq.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
    http://frontlinehq.com/css/style.css
    http://frontlinehq.com/js/bootstrap.min.js
    http://frontlinehq.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
    http://frontlinehq.com/js/tools.js
    https://gwb.lphbs.com/ConvivaCommunicationProxy.html
    http://www.shareasale.com/r.cfm?b=398769&u=908409&m=41388&urllink=&afftrack=
    http://secure.livechatinc.com/licence/2819642/script_data.js?groups=3&t=1403414083787&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shareasale.com%2Fr.cfm%3Fb%3D398769%26u%3D908409%26m%3D41388%26urllink%3D%26afftrack%3D&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwpengine.com%2F%3FSSAID%3D908409&params=&jsonp=__lc_data_10664
    http://secure.livechatinc.com/licence/2819642/localization.en.3.5e4860437b1dacc6a54ac8a5f442a878.js?jsonp=__lc_lang
```

Comment: Turn off each plugin seperately and check if the links still exist...

Comment: DOes this effect settings I've made with these plugins ? or I need to do the settings again?

Comment: @Programer Settings may or may not be retained after deactivation of a plugin - it all depends on the plugin. If you're worried about settings then set up a test install to test which plugin is causing the problem.

Comment: I figured https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/ this plugin  causes livechatinc.com URL but I looked in plugin file but didn't see any links